# For integers $x$, $y$ and prime $p$, does $x^2 \equiv -y^2 \pmod{p}$ imply $u^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory

For integers $x$, $y$ and prime $p$, does $x^2 \equiv -y^2 \pmod{p}$ imply $u^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ for some $u$?

Comment: Have a look into $\#12$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: @lab: How does that help?

Comment: @TonyK, If $p|y$ and when it does not

Answer (score 1):

Not if $x \equiv y \equiv 0 \mod p$. Otherwise yes: just take $u=x/y$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $x=y=p$ and $p=7$. Then, $x^{2}\equiv0\equiv-0\equiv-y^{2}\;\left(\text{mod }p\right)$. You can check to see that no element squares to be $6\equiv-1$.